# Stop auto hyphens in URLs

Tags: hyphenation

So let's say I have this long URL (or just happens to be at the end of a line), currently LaTeX will compile the document as:

```
something something http://This-
IsMyUrl.com
```

While the actual URL is `http://ThisIsMyUrl.com`. It will be fine in a pdf viewer but once it is printed on paper, the hyphen is not welcome.

My code for is standard: `\href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}`. I do it this way so that someone can go to that URL when reading it from paper. (`\href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}{Click here to learn more}` on paper is just silly)

I did a bit searching and so far `\allowbreak` somewhat works but it will turn the compiled document look like this:

```
% something something \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}{\allowbreak http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}
something            something
http://ThisIsMyUrl.com
```

It just looks so ugly. What I want is:

```
something something http://This
IsMyUrl.com
```

How can I do this without forcing the whole document to use no hyphens?

Comment: Are you looking for a simple `\url{<url here>}`?

Comment: It will change the font which causes inconsistent look and still has similar problem like `\allowbreak`@Johannes_B

Comment: `\urlstyle{same}` gets rid of the first problem. The second: I don't even know where `\allowbreaks` comes into place, since there is no [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html)

Comment: If you use `\href` the link text is considered to be normal text that's hyperlinked so hyphenates as text, if you use `\url` the system knows the visible text is a URL and changes its line breaking accordingly (the font used by url is customisable, see the url package)

Comment: Code is now included for my second example where `\allowbreak` is used. `\urlstyle{same}` works for a few scenarios but apparently now `\url` seeks punctuation for line break, and when a word is ultra loooong it will not do line break (but seems to have lots of questions about this on the internet).@Johannes_B

Answer (score 1):

I cannot follow the problem at hand.

Urls do not get hyphenated, link *text* gets hyphenated. It is *text*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
\parbox{7cm}{%
    Here is text and an url:
    \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309827/stop-auto-hyphens-in-urls}
}

\the\textwidth

\parbox{320pt}{%
    You can even have a hyperlink with an alternative text:
    \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309827/stop-auto-hyphens-in-urls}{No
    auto hyphenation in urls}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `\href` can be free, normal text and it will be hyphenated like normal text. So if you want a break without hyphen you will have to insert the necessary commands, e.g. a `\babelhyphen`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\textwidth=0.3cm

\begin{document}
bla \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309827/stop-auto-hyphens-in-urls}
{http://This\babelhyphen{empty}Is\babelhyphen{empty}My\babelhyphen{empty}Url.\babelhyphen{empty}com}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of package `url` for hyphenation of URLs is to hyphenate URLs without hyphen at special characters, which can be configured. URLs are not hyphenated between letters.

The following example shows several ways to set a URL via `hyperref`. `\nolinkurl` provides a URL without link, which can be used to format a URL or its fragments inside the second argument of `\href`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{1pt}}% narrow second column to force hyphenation
  \verb|\href|/plain:&
  \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}\\
\addlinespace
  \verb|\url|:&
  \url{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}\\
\addlinespace
  \verb|\href|+\verb|\nolinkurl|:&
  \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}{\nolinkurl{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}}\\
\addlinespace
  \verb|\href|+\verb|\nolinkurl|+\verb|same|:&
  \urlstyle{same}%
  \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}{\nolinkurl{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com}}\\
\addlinespace
  manual hyphenation:&
  \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}{\nolinkurl{http://This}}\hspace{0pt}%
  \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}{\nolinkurl{Is}}\hspace{0pt}%
  \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}{\nolinkurl{My}}\hspace{0pt}%
  \href{http://ThisIsMyUrl.com/}{\nolinkurl{Url.com}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]